# Django AWS S3 media files

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Working with Django, I am trying to use AWS S3 storage only for uploading and reading files which is working well at MEDIA_URL but the problem when using AWS S3 is that somehow I am losing reference to STATIC_URL where CSS and javascript files are

I only want MEDIA_URL pointing to S3 and keep my STATIC_URL away from AWS S3... Is that possible?

```
# Static asset configuration                                         
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)

if DEBUG:
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.environ['MEDIA_ROOT']
   MEDIA_URL = os.environ['MEDIA_URL']
else: 
   DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage'
   AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
   AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
   AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')
   MEDIA_URL = 'http://%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

Change STATIC_URL to "STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')". Could use decouple to hide those variables too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).